# How to retrieve a LongBlob from mySQL as a string in UTF-8 in grails?

Tags: mysql, grails, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to retrieve an object from a mysql db and one of the attributes in the entity is a String, in the database it is saved as a Longblob.

```
    String zipCode
    String streetName
    String description
    String metadata
    String status
    String cards
```

The attribute is cards

When I try to retrieve and "cards" has an accent or special character [à,á,è,ì,ñ, etc] it transforms it to an unreadable character "��".

When I get this same object from a Go app it does not have any problems with accents.

I've seen some similar questions about encoding in grails with the following solutions

> Add this string at the end of the connection URL

`"?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"`

> Change the config of grails with UTF-8

```
grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"
grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

But they did not work.

thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? And I'm assuming that your domain class like so, correct?
`static constraints = { cards sqlType: 'longblob' }`

Comment: What version of Grails are you using? I'm not having any issue reading special characters from a domain class using MySQL 5.6.51 with a Grails 4.0.11 application. The MySQL schema has `utf8` as the character set and `utf8_general_ci` is table collation. I did not add any parameters to the end of the connection URL.


CREATE SCHEMA `bookstore` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;

Comment: Does a Grails "String" imply characters?  A MySQL "longblob" implies no character structure.  What is in the column?